# How to install Mongodb and Mongosh in Ubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic)?

Tags: linux, database, mongodb, ubuntu, mongo-shell

I have tried installing MongoDB on my system by following many tutorials but none of them actually work.
On the official MongoDB documentation they have not provided any information for installation on **Ubuntu 22.10 or 22.04lts**, there is only installation guide for ubuntu 20.04 and below.

I am running ubuntu 22.10 and I really need to install MongoDB to continue my web development.
Please Help.

I have tried adding repositories.
Referred to these links,
but none of them seems to work.

https://tutorialforlinux.com/2022/11/19/mongodb-ubuntu-22-10-installation-step-by-step/3/
https://techviewleo.com/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-linux/
[Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRsjf.png)

Comment: Maybe try the obvious one: [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: Needs more details. What do you mean by "didn't work". What commands did you try, what happened, and what did you expect to happen instead? Please see [ask].

Comment: Maybe before criticizing his question ensure your criticism is valid.  
` `  
@WernfriedDomscheit: The generic "obvious" link does not cover Ubuntu 22.10.  
` `  
Robert: His third link ("Terminal Screenshot") shows the problem he got with one of the attempts.  
` `  
There has been some sort of security related change since Ubuntu 22.04 and newer guides either do not exist or did not bother to test.  
` `  
Neither of your comments were helpful, and Mongo doesn't seem to have included an up to date guide either.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: @BobbyCottle "none of them seems to work." is never considered as a valid or useful error message. According official doc, Ubuntu 22.10 seems not (yet) be supported.

Comment: The MongoDB documentation clearly states "The mongodb package provided by Ubuntu is not maintained by MongoDB Inc. and conflicts with the official mongodb-org package." I am not familiar with Ubuntu, but I think the first linked tutorial ignores this fact.